# Какие есть способы применения Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, веб-сервер

На Хабре и не только уже много раз были темы по поводу этого веб-сервера. Он быстрый, он работает на JS. Но для каких целей он нужен?

Я уже пробовал разбираться с ним, пока все что получилось - статичная страничка со счетчиком который почему-то прибавляет 2 а не 1 как положено. Складывается впечатление что на его базе не создать сайта в классическом понимании.

Comment: Для тех кто дружит с английским и хочет лучше понять - как это работает и где это может использоваться, может быть полезна [эта](http://bulk.fefe.de/scalable-networking.pdf) ссылка

Comment: А 2 прибавлял потому-что браузер по умолчанию делает запрос  на сервер в попытке получить **favicon.ico**, ваш "сервер" не проверял что именно запрашивается и не реагировал должным образом, посему при каждом запросе страницы счетчик увеличивался на 2.

По поводу не создать сайт - с таким пониманием как работает сервер - действительно написать что-либо не получится. На java вы бы 100% тоже не написали бы сайт, но это не значит что этого нельзя сделать :D

На данный момент nodejs имеет все для создания высоконагружених вертикально и горизонтально расширяемых серверов.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Как я понял, разработчик(и) и не ставит (ставят) целью создать полноценный сервер. Из параграфа About (а точнее первых строк) следует, что это просто миниатюрный инструмент по работе с сокетами и тому подобными средствами "общения".

Comment: Вроде еще на Ajax запросы быстро отвечает.
Мне как раз и интересно что еще можно сделать при его помощи кроме инструмента для быстрого обмена сообщениями.

Comment: https://github.com/ry/node/wiki

Comment: http://nodejs.ru/ тут вроде бы что то интересное есть вроде загрузки файлов.
хоть что то)

Answer (score 2):

Как это нельзя? Можно всё то же самое, только язык на сервере - JavaScript. Да посмотрите на офсайт Node.JS.. там прямо на главной странице показано, как это делается.

> > пока все что получилось - статичная страничка со счетчиком который почему-то прибавляет 2 а не 1 как положено

Если страница статичная, то при чём тут Node.JS? А если нет, то значит она уже не статичная. В обоих случаях это не его косяк ;)

Comment: Разве там возможно разбить сайт на страницы? Как в классическом apache или nginx или iis или еще каком http сервере?

Comment: А он не для создания сайтов, чисто системная фигня, как я понял.

Comment: Ну вам ведь никто не запрещает делить свой код на файлы.. а то как это выглядит внешне - это вообще не имеет значения. Понятие файл для веб-сервера - весьма относительно.